# Controlling a BLDC at low speeds

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor

I want to try and implement a steer by wire system with two BLDCs. The task requires rotating the BLDC at low speeds.

I have a 30A simonk ESC as the driver, and an arduino MEGA as the microcontroller. I was messing around with the PWM values to see how the BLDC responds. I ran a for loop with PWM ranging from 0 to 255, and the motor did not run at all for values <130, and then suddenly starts to move rapidly at a pWM of 131. For other values, the motor makes a beeping sound but doesn't move at all.

How can I control the driver so that I can ensure that the motor starts to move at a low speed, say at a PWM of 15?

Comment: You either need gearing or sensored BLDC control. Sensorless is no good at low speeds. In other words, it's not a problem that can be fixed with software. You potentially also need to add a sine-drive but that's not enough on its own. Besides, a sensorless BLDC doesn't even know the absolute position of the rotor so your motor controller is completely unsuited for the task.

Comment: SimonK 'PWM' is the same as normal hobby ESCs and servos, a 1~2ms pulse repeated ~50-200 times per second (the 'frame rate'), creating 0% to 100% PWM at the motor. Only the width matters. Pulse widths less than 1ms or greater than 2ms may cause the motor to 'beep' as an error indication.

Comment: You can drive a BLDC as though it was a stepper motor (open loop) at very low speeds though like a stepper it'll be quite inefficient. You'll almost certainly have to roll your own BLDC driver if you want that pleasure; commercial BLDC controllers (especially those that describe themselves as ESCs) won't support it.

Comment: You have picked your solution without fully defining your problem. Basically I read this as electric power steering. What is the torque requirements? Is this a model or real car? What is the available voltage range, is it clean. What are the peak loads the motor will see. You stated PWM from 0-255 what voltage, frequency, duty cycle, etc? Please explain why PWM is the most important specification. You have two BLDCs what are the and what are there ratings. Post links to all hardware devices that show technical details. Please reword your question with a much better explanation of what you want